# Create new issue GitHub iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, github, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I am trying to implement a bug report page into my app. The user provides the username and password and bug title and description and i do the REST (lol). Anyway this is my code:

```
+(void)reportBug:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password title:(NSString *)title description:(NSString *)body completion:(void (^)(id))completion{
    NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"body" : body, @"title" : title, @"assignee" : username};
    AFHTTPSessionManager *session = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.github.com"] sessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    [session POST:@"/repos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues" parameters:myDict constructingBodyWithBlock:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id  responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"everything is %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    completion (error);
    }];
}
```

I didn't really find the documentation very clear but maybe I'm just stupid. I'm getting this error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8a92a1de40> { URL: https://api.github.com/repos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues } { status code: 404, headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" = "ETag, Link, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Security-Policy" = "default-src 'none'";
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Sun, 10 Jan 2016 16:20:51 GMT";
Server = "GitHub.com";
Status = "404 Not Found";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = deny;
"X-GitHub-Media-Type" = "github.v3";
"X-GitHub-Request-Id" = "51AB3A71:12180:25A43C4:569284E3";
"X-RateLimit-Limit" = 60;
"X-RateLimit-Remaining" = 46;
"X-RateLimit-Reset" = 1452445261;
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.github.com/repos/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226d65 73736167 65223a22 4e6f7420 466f756e 64222c22 646f6375 6d656e74 6174696f 6e5f7572 6c223a22 68747470 733a2f2f 64657665 6c6f7065 722e6769 74687562 2e636f6d 2f76332f 69737375 65732f23 63726561 74652d61 6e2d6973 73756522 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}
```

Comment: No. Do i need to? because that wouldnt really make sense

Comment: nvm, it's a public repo.
What does the resulting request look like? It looks like the API is expecting JSON, what if you send an NSDictionary instead of an NSString?

Comment: yeah thats what i was thinking. How would i go about converting it into json and sending it?

Comment: Just send an NSDictionary with the keys and objects as shown in the API. eg. @{@"body" : body, @"title" : title, <etc>}

Comment: see updated answer. still getting same error

Comment: May need to set the request serializer to an AFJSONRequestSerializer
What does the resulting request look like? Could also try a GET to double-check it's working properly. Opening that link in a browser works fine.

Comment: tried '[session setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];' is this the correct way to set the serialser? becuase its not working. Also how do i show you what the resulting request looks like

Comment: What do you mean it's not working?
`task` in the completion block should have an `NSURLRequest` `currentRequest` or `originalRequest` object. Otherwise [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) is a useful tool.

Comment: as in i am getting the same error in console

Comment: Did you try the GET?

Comment: sorry, i didnt see that. Yes get works fine with no params but when i try to put params in it doesnt work unless i convert the nsdictionary to json manually.However when i do this with the post i get the same error.

Comment: by manually i mean using a function someone else wrote

Comment: The error you are getting back is: `{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue"}`.

Comment: Yes, in the documentation they say the sometimes substitute error 403 with 404 for privacy reasons so I'm going to use the afoauth2manager so authenticate the request to see if that does anythinv

Answer (score 1):

You have to be authenticated in order to be able to POST new issue.